# Functions overridden fromThreadPoolExecutor for logging

Tags: java, concurrency

```
// code exactly taken from java concurrency in practice

public class TimingThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  private final ThreadLocal<Long> startTime
    = new ThreadLocal<Long>();
  private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("TimingThreadPool");
  private final AtomicLong numTasks = new AtomicLong();
  private final AtomicLong totalTime = new AtomicLong();

  protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
    log.fine(String.format("Thread %s: start %s", t, r));
    startTime.set(System.nanoTime());
  }

  protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    try {
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long taskTime = endTime - startTime.get();
    numTasks.incrementAndGet();
    totalTime.addAndGet(taskTime);
    log.fine(String.format("Thread %s: end %s, time=%dns",
            t, r, taskTime));
    } finally {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    }
}

protected void terminated() {
try {
    log.info(String.format("Terminated: avg time=%dns",
            totalTime.get() / numTasks.get()));
    } finally {
    super.terminated();
    }
}
}
```

Is the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance is shared by all the worker threads. If yes then the method `beforeExecute(...)` and `afterExecute(...)` shouldn't be synchronized? If the answer is NO then is the reason is " the local variables are assigned in thread stack and the state variables like numTasks, totalTime, startTime are thread confined / atomic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to synchronized beforeExecute and afterExecute because all fields used in these two methods are thread-safe java.util.logging.Logger (from API - all methods on Logger are multi-thread safe.) or ThreadLocal and AtocmicLong specially designed for lock-free usage.

As for local variables they are accessible to only one thread and do not need any synchronization.

Comment: Local variables ( endTime, taskTime) inside these methods need not be made atomic because its allocated inside thread stack so thread confined and hence no need atomic. Am i correct?

Comment: Please answer the 1st part "Is the ThreadPoolExecutor instance is shared by all the worker threads?"

Comment: That is correct. This is because a local variable is on a thread stack and is visible only from this and the only thread. Synchronization is about two or more threads sharing the same resource

Comment: As for "Is the ThreadPoolExecutor instance is shared.." I'd rather say "Worker is an inner class of ThreadPoolExecutor so all workers have access to ThreadPoolExecutor members / fields"

Comment: I'd also mention that terminated is only works because afterExecute will not be called again during it's call.  Otherwise some more code would be needed to make sure the average calculation are see consistent values for totalTime and numTasks.